# how to remove last lines from CSV file

Tags: bash, shell

I am inserting SQL query result into a csv file. At the end of file two rows are getting added as shown below. Can anyone please tell me how to delete these two rows (bank row and '168 rows selected'). 
Also, it will be great if these rows don't get inserted into csv file in the first place while inserting sql query result into csv file.

```
pvm:0a12dd82,pvm:0a12dd84,TechnicalErrorProcess,21-JUN-19 07.01.58.560000 AM,pi_halted,38930,1
pvm:0a12dd77,pvm:0a12dd79,TechnicalErrorProcess,20-JUN-19 12.36.27.384000 PM,pi_halted,1572846,1
pvm:0a12dd6t,pvm:0a12dd6v,TechnicalErrorProcess,20-JUN-19 12.05.22.145000 PM,pi_halted,38929,1
pvm:0a12dd4h,pvm:0a12dd4l,TechnicalErrorProcess,17-JUN-19 07.11.43.522000 AM,pi_halted,9973686,1

168 rows selected.
```

Comment: head -n -2 output.csv   edit: Also depending on what sql engine you're using you can actually suppress these e.g. in oracle you'd use something like SET FEEDBACK OFF

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It worked.... Could you please let me know how can I insert the database column names in CSV file as first row. I am using oracle database.

Comment: There are lots of ways to display headings and format them - too much for this comment really. You can read the sqlplus docs e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_six.htm#SQPUG463   - You'll normally get them displayed (unless you have them turned off), but even then they might not be listed as what you want e.g. total might want to be output as TOTAL_COST or something - that page outlines them. Sometimes I might do a pseudo select instead of doing the pure format route e.g. 'select col1, col2 from dual union all select total, id from table;' YMMV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a negative number for the `-n` parameter using the `head` command:

> -n, --lines=[-]K
>       print the first K lines instead of the first 10; with the leading '-', print all but the last K lines of each file

so:

```sh
head -n -2 input-file.txt > output-file.txt
```

Comment: Thank a lot it worked... I had to update the command like head -n -3 input-file.txt > output-file.txt. With -2 blank line was still present.

Could you please let me know how can I insert the database column names in CSV file as first row. I am using oracle database.

Comment: You should create a new question for that

Answer (score 4):

For MSSQL, before select query append the following,

```
set nocount on; select ...
```

I'm not sure if that will work for other databases.

Answer (score 2):

Filter the output of the command above to exclude to two last lines.

I see two ways for doing it with a bash command:

```
head --lines=-2
```

Or

```
sed -e '/rows selected/d' -e '/^ *$/d'
```

(Indeed, this was a placeholder).

Comment: What's the Or... `head -n -2` (in short form)?

Comment: I think this was a placeholder so he could submit an answer quickly and then edit it afterwards.

Comment: maybe he'll post `head -n $(($(wc -l input-file.txt | awk '${print $0}') - 2)) input-file.txt`